# How to listen UDP Sockets continously on a rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, udp, ruby-on-rails-5

Im setting up a new server on rails where i need to keep listening on a port to receive messages and stored them in my database. The problem is that the server ahve to be listening all the time to the port and i dont know where i may write the sniffer inside ruby to do this withouth interruption.

I made this exact project in Node using express and a library for Datagrams, all i need to do was create the sniffer on the main file that was always running, but I dont know how to do this on rails.

This a sniffer a found in ruby

```
require 'socket.so'
ul = UDPSocket.new
ul.bind("localhost", 4001)
p ul.recvfrom(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails really isn't designed for this.  However you can start with the script in your question and make it a daemon with https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons

Then talk to your Rails app via HTTP/API or alternatively directly to your database.

Comment: I never hear before about the daemons im interest in them, but there is a way to start the daemons inside my rails app or i should initialized rails and my daemons separately?

Comment: @DanielDaza you can start the daemons like `ruby myscript.rb start` and stop `ruby myscript.rb stop` etc.  I would start them seperately.

Comment: Thanks but i find i way to do it inside rails, using Active Job

Answer (score 0):

At first, by looking at your request, I am very curious about what you are wanting to achieve. 
As suggested in this other post: [Does Rails support a neat way of listening to a UDP socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967598/does-rails-support-a-neat-way-of-listening-to-a-udp-socket/1967668) 
Rails is a web application development framework, not really a server daemon framework. So, it may be a good idea to think about starting the UDP listener on a different process (which you can start separately).

Depending on the requirements, WebSockets with ActionCable could be good to look at if you are willing to provide real-time bi-directional communication with your application (https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html).

If you are really wanting to just spin off a UDP listener in your rails application, you can still hook a socket listener in the rails initialization process and run it in a distinct thread/process. But, I find this quite odd.

Comment: I making the server for a GPS tracker so and i receive the GPS data by UDP so i need to sniff a port constantly.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is Creating an Active Job for the Sniffer and calling it inside the config.ru file the initialize the rails server